# Proving that $\frac{2\pi i}{f'(z_0)}=\oint_\gamma \frac{dz}{f(z) - f(z_0)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I have the following exercise that I'm having some trouble solving:

> Let $f:U\to\mathbb C$ be an holomorphic function, and let $f'(z_0) \neq 0,z_0 \in U$. Prove that, if $\gamma=z_0+re^{it}$ with $t \in [0,2\pi]$, then, for a sufficiently small amount of $r$, we have that:
>
> $$\frac{2\pi i}{f'(z_0)}=\oint_\gamma \frac{dz}{f(z) - f(z_0)}$$

And then They gave the following tip:

> **Tip:** Notice that the function
>
> $$g(z)=\frac{z - z_0}{f(z) - f(z_0)}$$
> has a removable singularity in $z = z_0$

---

**My attempt:**

I checked and indeed the function $g(z)$ has a removable singularity in $z = z_0$. This means that: $\text{Res}(g,z_0) = 0$ and because of the residue theorem we have that:

$$\oint_\gamma \frac{z - z_0}{f(z) - f(z_0)} = 2 \pi i \text{Res}(g,z_0)\text{Ind}_\gamma (z_0)$$

Giving us:

$$\oint_\gamma \frac{z - z_0}{f(z) - f(z_0)} = 0$$

This integral is similar to the formula we are trying to prove but I don't know where to go from here. Maybe we need to find some other thing that is equal to $0$ and then equal that some other thing to $\oint_\gamma \frac{z - z_0}{f(z) - f(z_0)}$. How should I continue the proof?

Comment: What if $f(z)=1$ for all $z$?

Comment: Apply the residue theorem and L'Hospital's Rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\bar{g}$ be defined by $\bar{g}(z_0)=1/f'(z_0)$ and $\bar{g}(z) = g(z)$ for $z \neq z_0.$ Note that $\bar{g}$ is holomorphic in an neighborhood of $z_0$. Therefore we can use [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula):
$$
\frac{1}{f'(z_0)}
= \bar{g}(z_0) 
= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{\bar{g}(z)}{z-z_0} dz
= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{1}{f(z)-f(z_0)} dz
$$

Comment: But $g(z_0)$ is not defined so does it make any sense to write $g(z_0)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{g(z)}{z - z_0}dz$?

Comment: And can we even apply Cauchy integral formula if inside the contour there exists a singularity, and the function is not holomorphic everywhere inside the contour?

Comment: $g(z_0)$ is not defined, but since the singularity is removable we can define $g(z_0) = 1/f'(z_0)$ to make $g$ holomorphic in a neighborhood of $z_0$.

Comment: @Eduude. I made a change in my answer.

Comment: It is not given that $ f'(z_0)\neq 0$. Besides you have proved  the result only for $z=z_0$.

Comment: It is given that $f'(z_0) \neq 0$, I made a mistake and instead wrote $f(z_0) \neq 0$. Sorry

Comment: @Eduude. And shouldn't it be $\frac{2\pi i}{f'(z_0)}$ in the formula? Because $z$ is not a free variable, while $z_0$ is.

Comment: @md2perpe yes, I made a mistake while typing, I'm sorry

Comment: @Eduude. Any doubts now about my answer?

Comment: No, It's all clear, thanks

Comment: This implicitly uses something like Riemann's removable singularity theorem -- $\bar{g}$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $z_0$ by assumption, and continuous at $z_0$ by definition, but you either need to i) argue Cauchy's integral formula applies to functions which only fail to be holomorphic at discrete points (where it remains bounded) or ii) to invoke the removable singularities theorem to conclude that $\bar{g}$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $z_0$.